# TinyMCE: Disable default wrapping for anchor element

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce, wysiwyg

I would like to have the ability to override anchor styles globally and to achieve this I need to change the wrapping behavior as shown in the examples below:

Default behavior:

```html
<span style="font-family: &quot;arial black&quot;, sans-serif;" data-mce-style="font-family: 'arial black', sans-serif;">
   <strong>
      <a href="https://google.com" data-mce-href="https://google.com" data-mce-linkchecker-status="valid" data-mce-selected="inline-boundary">Some text</a>
   </strong>
</span>
```

Desired behaviour

```html
<a href="https://google.com" data-mce-href="https://google.com" data-mce-linkchecker-status="valid" data-mce-selected="inline-boundary">
   <span style="font-family: &quot;arial black&quot;, sans-serif;" data-mce-style="font-family: 'arial black', sans-serif;">
      <strong>
         Some text
      </strong>
   </span>
</a>
```